# Python disabling startmenu and taskbar

Tags: python, process

I have a python tkinter app. Whenever my app is running, i want my window startmenu, desktop icons and task bar to be disappeared.

I actually managed to get the required result by manually going into the windows task manager and killing the process 'explorer.exe'.

But when i tried to write a python script to do that automatically like this:

```
import os
os.system("taskkill /im explorer.exe")
```

It is actually bringing up the shutting down window instead of hiding the startmenu and taskbar.

Is there any way i can lock down(or even hide) the startmenu and taskbar with the python script?

EDIT:
The script will be used on

windows XP pro 32bit

python 2.7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass `/f` as a parameter there, it should work:

```
os.system('taskkill /f /im explorer.exe')
```

Edit: Yap, it worked. Tested it myself..

Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: What about restarting it? If I try os.system('explorer.exe') I simply get an explorer window and not the Windows bar...