# How to remove the hotkey for the Windows key using Python

Tags: python, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am working on an application, using the [python keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) package, and I want to overwrite the windows key to do something else.

I am able to successfully add a hotkey for the `cmd` button, which is the windows key, but when i press the windows key it opens the Windows menu from the bottom left *and* does the action I assigned it.

How can I remove/overwrite the existing windows key function, so that the new hotkey I am registering is the only action?

Code:

```
self._keyboard.add_hotkey('cmd', do_something())
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a makeshift method that works for my situation (I needed to disable the taskbar as well).

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694159/python-disabling-startmenu-and-taskbar). Hides the task bar, and prevents the windows start menu from opening.

Probably does not work on Ubuntu/Linux.